# find files recursive and save in dymanic array (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to make use of dynamic arrays in VBA in order to save the found strings and use the `FileSystemObject` to find the files.

The code I currently use is this one

```
Private Sub cmdStartSearch_Click()
    Dim resultList(0) As String
    Call FindFile(resultList, ".png", "Q:\", True)
End Sub

Private Sub FindFile(ByRef resultList() As String, target As String, ByVal aPath As String, useSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim myFileSystemObject As FileSystemObject, curFolder As folder, folder As folder
    Dim folColl As Folders, file As file, fileColl As Files
    Set myFileSystemObject = New FileSystemObject
    Set curFolder = myFileSystemObject.GetFolder(aPath)
    Set folderList = curFolder.SubFolders
    Set fileList = curFolder.Files

    For Each file In fileList
        ReDim Preserve resultList(1 To UBound(resultList) + 1) As String
        If InStr(file.Name, target) > 0 Then
            resultList(UBound(resultList)) = file.Name
            Debug.Print file.Name
        End If
    Next

    If useSubfolders Then
        For Each folder In folderList
            DoEvents        'Yield execution so other events may be processed
            If Not foundTarget Then
                 FindFile resultList, target, folder.Path, useSubfolders
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set myFileSystemObject = Nothing
    Set curFolder = Nothing
    Set folderList = Nothing
    Set fileList = Nothing
End Sub
```

This fails however with `Array is fixed or or temporarily locked`.

How can I get around this problem, or solve the original one?

Comment: Change `UBound(resultList) + 1` to `UBound(resultList)` `Ubound` is not 0-based.

Comment: @JLILIAman, Could you explain a bit what you mean by UBound is not 0-based, please.

Comment: Ubound will count subscripts including the 0th of subscript of resutlList so there is no need to add 1.

Comment: @JLILIAman, So if the array holds arr(0)=76, arr(1)=77. The UBound(arr) would yield 2 or 1? By your description it should return 2, as 0 is counted as 1 and 1 is counted as 2. However I think it should give 1 as the answer, not two.

Comment: That does not seem to be the actual problem. I defined now the list as uninitialized `Dim resultList() As String`, but now get the error `Subscript out of range`

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech, which line are you getting the error? Are you using the code I have given?

Answer (score 0):

I feel this has a far better/easier solution. What you do is loop through the file list as you did but then return a long string with the file names and then finally break it using the Split function which will yield you a String array anyway.

Your code could simply change as,

```
Private Sub cmdStartSearch_Click()
    Dim resultList() As String
    resultList = Split(FindFile(".png", "Q:\", True), ";")
End Sub

Private Function FindFile(target As String, ByVal aPath As String, useSubfolders As Boolean) As String
    Dim retStr As String
    Dim myFileSystemObject As FileSystemObject, curFolder As folder, folder As folder
    Dim folColl As Folders, file As file, fileColl As Files
    Set myFileSystemObject = New FileSystemObject
    Set curFolder = myFileSystemObject.GetFolder(aPath)
    Set folderList = curFolder.SubFolders
    Set fileList = curFolder.Files

    For Each file In fileList
        If InStr(file.Name, target) > 0 Then
            retStr = retStr & ";" & file.Name
            Debug.Print file.Name
        End If
    Next

    If useSubfolders Then
        For Each folder In folderList
            DoEvents        'Yield execution so other events may be processed
            If Not foundTarget Then
                retStr = retStr & ";" & FindFile(target, folder.Path, useSubfolders)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Set myFileSystemObject = Nothing
    Set curFolder = Nothing
    Set folderList = Nothing
    Set fileList = Nothing

    If Len(retStr) > 0 Then retStr = Right(retStr, Len(retStr)-1)

    FindFile = retStr
End Function
```

Why are the variables ***folderList***, ***fileList***, ***foundTarget*** not declared in the context?

Comment: The code was mainly copied so I do not know why some variables are not defined. In general- is your approach common in vba? I find it usefull, but still strange that working with array is so complicated.

Comment: Arrays in VBA is a bit tricky, but this solution could be a lot easier than the way you want it to be done ! Split is a very common method used to return a String array.